# validate SGML DTD

Tags: validation, dtd, sgml

I wrote the following SGML DTD:

```
<!DOCTYPE tvguide[
    <!ELEMENT tvguide--(date,channel+)>
    <!ELEMENT date--(#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT channel--(channel_name,format?,program*)>
    <!ELEMENT channel--(#PCDATA)>
    <!ATTLIST channel teletext (yes|no) "no">
    <!ELEMENT format--(#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT program--(name,start_time,(end_time|duration))>
    <!ATTLIST program
        min_age CDATA #REQUIRED
        lang CDATA #IMPLIED es>
    <!ELEMENT name--(#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT start_time--(#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT end_time--(#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT duration--(#PCDATA)>]>
```

Which tool should I use to check if there are any syntax errors and where, and if it's a valid SGML DTD?

Which tool should I use to validate files using this DTD? I would prefer a program for windows but a linux binary or a library written in PHP, C, C++, Java or Javascript also would be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [SP from James Clark](http://www.jclark.com/sp/). I use OmniMark to validate SGML, but I don't think you can find copies anymore.

You should get errors about tag minimization (you need spaces before/after/between the `--`). You should also get errors about the element `channel` being declared twice and an error about the "es" in the `lang` attribute declaration for `program`.

Here's a valid version for reference:

```
 <!DOCTYPE tvguide [
 <!ELEMENT tvguide - - (date,channel+)>
 <!ELEMENT date - - (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT channel - - (channel_name,format?,program*)>
 <!ATTLIST channel teletext (yes|no) "no">
 <!ELEMENT format - - (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT program - - (name,start_time,(end_time|duration))>
 <!ATTLIST program
      min_age CDATA #REQUIRED
      lang CDATA "es">
 <!ELEMENT name - - (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT start_time - - (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT end_time - - (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT duration - - (#PCDATA)>
 ]>
```

Comment: [Omnimark](http://www.stilo.com/OmniMark/OmniMark10/tabid/770/Default.aspx) is still available from Stilo International PLC.  I don't know off hand whether Omnimark still includes an SGML parser, but it wouldn't surprise me if it did.

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen - Thank you for the link. I contacted Stilo a couple of years ago about licensing, but never heard back. I'm still using 5.3.

Comment: @Daniel, sounds like you didn't have enough zeros after your name;-)

Answer (score 3):

Note that "valid SGML DTD" is technically a bit ambiguous: it depends with respect to which "SGML declaration" is used, which is where things are specified like the maximum length of a *name* or even which characters can occur in a *name*. That's the "*concrete syntax*" used in a particular DTD (and hence in a particular SGML document).

The "default" syntax for SGML is called the "*reference concrete syntax*" and is defined in ISO 8879:1986. Because in this syntax the maximum length of names (the so-called "*NAMELEN quantity*") is set to 8 (eight), and LOW LINE (`_`) can't be used in *names* (it is not a so-called *name character* there), your DTD would **not** be valid with respect to the *reference concrete syntax*.

HTML—for example—uses its own [SGML declaration](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/sgmldecl.html): it hugely increases the *NAMELEN quantity* and adds `_` to the *name characters*, among other changes. With respect to this concrete syntax, your DTD would indeed be *syntactically* valid.

---

But then there is no *element declaration* for `channel_name`, but the DTD requires at least one such element to be present in `tvguide` (namely, contained in the required element `channel`). [Leaving out a declaration for an *element type* that does not occur in the document is, by itself, not an error or a problem.]

So the DTD is not (yet) "valid" in the sense that you can't write any *document elements* (ie, `tvguide` elements, or simply "documents") that are valid according to it.

---

Adding a straightforward declaration for `channel_name` like

```
<!ELEMENT channel_name (#PCDATA)>
```

remedies that—now for example the *document element*

```
<tvguide>
  <date>2016</date>
  <channel><channel_name>XTV</channel_name></channel>
</tvguide>
```

is *valid* according to your DTD. (I tried it out using the SP parser, mentioned in the other answer.)

---

Simplifying the names in your DTD would make the whole thing a valid "*Basic SGML Document*", and even a valid "*Minimal SGML Document*"—these terms (again from ISO 8879) come closest to the notion of "valid SGML" when no specific context and SGML declaration is given: they basically mean "portable and acceptable to any SGML system". Here is my proposed version:

```
<!DOCTYPE tvguide [
 <!ELEMENT tvguide  - - (date,channel+)>
 <!ELEMENT date     - - (#PCDATA)>

 <!ELEMENT channel  - - (ch-name,format?,program*)>
 <!ATTLIST channel
           teletext (yes|no) no>

 <!ELEMENT format   - - (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT ch-name  - - (#PCDATA)>

 <!ELEMENT program  - - (name,start-tm,(end-tm|duration))>
 <!ATTLIST program
           min-age  CDATA    #REQUIRED
           lang     CDATA    "es">

 <!ELEMENT name     - - (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT start-tm - - (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT end-tm   - - (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT duration - - (#PCDATA)>
]>
<tvguide>
 <date>2016-12-11</date>
 <channel><ch-name>X-TV 4</ch-name></channel>
</tvguide>
```